# Programatically restrict by ReceivedTime, what date/time format can I use?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

On my system, (Outlook 2016, Windows 10), if I use the following search restrictions on my folders, it works as expected.

```
...
var filter = $"[ReceivedTime]> '{dt.ToString("ddd M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")}'";
var items = folder.Items.Restrict(filter);
foreach( var item in items )
{
  ...
```

But I am concerned that the date format, `"ddd M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"` might not work on some systems. Especially in cases where the months and days might cause confusion, (days <= 12)

What would be the best way to ensure that the filter will work on any system using whatever local my users might have.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.ToString(“g”)` to convert to the culture specific general date short time format.

In case of `en-US` this will be `4/10/2008 6:30 AM`.

More about the format specifier [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-general-date-short-time-g-format-specifier).

Additional useful info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison), it shows that you can call a Format method inside your filter string and let Outlook take care of the formatting. Although I think just using the `g` format specifier would work in your case.